# How do I configure SonarQube to annotate GitHub Pull Requests with reduced coverage?

Tags: github, sonarqube

We'd like to setup SonarQube so that it reports reduction of test coverage on pull requests.

It already reports lots of other issues on the pull request, but for us, it's just missing this one feature.

Is SonarQube capable of annotating reduced test coverage on commits? Or do we need to use another service such as http://coveralls.io for this?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is planned for future versions. This would require some update both in the platform and in the GitHub plugin.

You can follow: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6763